# IllegalStateException within method with Response paramether

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I wrote a simple class to test response reading entity method (if it works as I expect). But it didn't worked well.

When I launch my class I get following error at `response.readEntity()`:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not supported on an outbound message.  
>   at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(OutboundJaxrsResponse.java:150)
> ```

And here's the code I wrote

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Entity> representations = new ArrayList<>();
        representations.add(new Entity("foo", "baz", false));
        representations.add(new Entity("foo1", "baz1", true));
        representations.add(new Entity("foo2", "baz2", false));
        Response build = Response.ok(representations).build();
        printEntitesFromResponse(build);
    }

public static void printEntitesFromResponse(Response response) {
        response
                .readEntity(new GenericType<List<Entity>>() {})
                .stream()
                .forEach(entity -> System.out.println(entity));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are two types of `Response`s, inbound and outbound, though they still use the same interface. Outbound is when you are sending a response from the server-side

```
Response response = Response.ok(entity).build();
```

Inbound is when you are receiving the response on the client-side.

```
Response response = webTarget.request().get();
```

The `readEntity()` method is disabled on the server-side outbound response because you don't need it. It's only used when you need to *de*-serialize the response from the response stream. But there is none when it's outbound.

If you want the entity on the outbound response, just use [`Response#getEntity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getEntity--)

Comment: And what type of object is webTarged supposed to be?

Comment: WebTarget......

Comment: The use of the `getEntity()` does not help, as I cannot pass in `String.class` as parameter. I need the Request as XML-String for debugging purposes. Can't be so super hard! Thx.

Comment: Response#getEntity() returns Object and requires type cast. Is it possible to get the result of a concrete type using Response#getEntity()?

Answer (score 2):

You can mock the response directly using Mockito. Something like this

```
private final Response response = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
```

And then you can mock required responses when `readEntity` method is called.

```
Mockito.when(response.readEntity(String.class)).thenReturn("result");
```