# Jersey endpoint with SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream

Tags: http, jersey, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I have a jersey v2.30 application using **jersey-container-grizzly2-http** and **jersey-grizzly-connector**. I have an endpoint which returns a pdf file, the endpoint seems to work which means the client gets the file successfully, however on the server side I can see the exception below.

From google seems like this error means the client is closing the connection and I would like to dig a little bit more and understand why is doing that and what can I do to stop this from happening.

```
Mar 26, 2020 10:58:56 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder writeResponse
SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1116)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:638)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:371)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:361)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:356)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:441)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:663)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NIOOutputStreamImpl.write(NIOOutputStreamImpl.java:59)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:276)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter.writeTo(ReaderWriter.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeTo(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InputStreamProvider.writeTo(InputStreamProvider.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InputStreamProvider.writeTo(InputStreamProvider.java:37)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:61)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.writeCompositeBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:47)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleWrite(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleWrite(TransportFilter.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:866)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:834)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:1068)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:695)
    ... 32 more
```

This is the code:

```
@POST
@Path("/au/last-mile-label")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Object postLastMileAu(UberShipment shipment) {

    EntityManager em = MyPonyApp.emf.createEntityManager();

    String carrier = "apiProvider1";

    Response response = CarrierApiFactory.carrierApiMapping.get(carrier)
            .createDomesticShipmentAndCreateAndGetLabelLastMile(
                    em, 
                    shipment);

    em.close();

    return response;
}

@Override
public Response createDomesticShipmentAndCreateAndGetLabelLastMile(EntityManager em, UberShipment uberShipment) {

    String shipmentId = this.createShipment(em, uberShipment, uberShipment.getLastMileOrigin(), uberShipment.getLastMileDestination());

    ...

    return this.getLabel(em, request_id);
}

public Response getLabel(EntityManager em, String request_id) {

    ...

    return getLabelFromUrl(jsonNode.get("labels").elements().next().get("url").textValue());
}

private Response getLabelFromUrl(String url) {

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
            .register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME), Level.INFO, null, null));

    client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 2000);
    client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 20000);

    Invocation.Builder req = client.target(url)
            .request()
            .header("client_id", api_key);

    Response response = req.get(Response.class);

    return response;
}
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated

thank you

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with this, but you [NEED to read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36949363/2587435). You can't do what you're doing in your code, i.e. returning a Client Response as a server Response. They are not the same thing.